I'm looking for help in adding custom fields in existed odoo addon
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_mail_mass_mailing_search">
        <field name="name">mailing.mailing.search</field>
        <field name="model">mailing.mailing</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <search string="Mailings">
                <field name="name" string="Mailing" filter_domain="['|', ('name', 'ilike', self), ('subject', 'ilike', self)]"/>
                <field name="campaign_id" string="Campaign" groups="mass_mailing.group_mass_mailing_campaign"/>
                <field name="invoice_url" widget="url" string="Invoice URL"/>
                <filter string="My Mailings" name="assigned_to_me"
                        domain="[('user_id', '=', uid)]"
                        help="Mailings that are assigned to me"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter name="filter_sent_date" date="sent_date"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter string="A/B Tests" name="filter_ab_test" domain="[('ab_testing_enabled', '=', True)]"/>
                <filter string="A/B Tests to review" name="filter_ab_test_to_review"
                    domain="[('ab_testing_enabled', '=', True), ('ab_testing_winner_selection', '=', 'manual'), ('ab_testing_completed', '=', False)]"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter name="inactive" string="Archived" domain="[('active', '=', False)]"/>
                <group expand="0" string="Group By">
                    <filter string="Status" name="group_state" context="{'group_by': 'state'}"/>
                    <filter string="Sent By" name="sent_by" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'email_from'}"/>
                    <separator/>
                    <filter string="Sent Period" name="sent_date" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'sent_date'}"/>
                </group>
            </search>
        </field>
    </record>

Field "invoice_url" does not exist in model "mailing.mailing"
im wanted to add url in mail sending form in odoo 17 downside of attach a file section but here is error and added this field  into mailing_mailing.py model  but still has occured same error

"here is error" - what error? Include the complete text of any error messages you see.

Field "invoice_url" does not exist in model "mailing.mailing"

That means this field "invoice_url" not exist in python model .
So you need to add this field in "mailing.mailing" model in python
